# Transfer Schema and Rebuild Databse on Another Server

Tags: linux, mysql, database

I have made a number of changes to the database schema on my development including the addition of new tables and changes to others. Is there an easy way to transfer this schema to the server, build the new tables and rebuild the others without having to duplicate all the changes I have spent around 15 hours implementing?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but this kind of thing is a bit easier to do if you plan a bit up front.

### Changes

When you create a database migration (think schema change) you need to create a `sql` statement that will encapsulate the change. If you are adding a column to an existing table with data in it you should be able to create the `sql` statement that describes the change. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable`.`local`
   ADD COLUMN `last_update` timestamp NULL AFTER `location_name`,
    ...;
```

If you keep a `sql` file with statements that tracks each change then run the statements in the right order on your production tables, life should be good. You can even add this kind of stuff to your version control if your are tracking such things. This is probably the best way to do this without help from a framework that already has this support.

### New Tables

New Stuff is easier. Fuss with it until you have all your indexes and data types figured out then just dump the schema to a `.sql` file. Run this on your production server and the table should be there.

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -pmypassword databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

The `-d` should only dump the schema and not the data.

### The Hard Way

If you haven't kept a running list of incremental changes or have made schema breaking changes then its gonna be a bit harder. You may have to manually diff the schema on the production tables and the develepoment ones and create the migrations by hand. I am assuming that you haven't changed tables so drastically that existing data will no longer fit the field definitions.

You could probably just dump the schema from your production tables, import it into another database on your development machine and then create your migrations there. But bear in mind that this will probably go faster than it took to design the new schema since you just have to create the migration to the new schema from the old one.